# Converting XML to BsonArray in MongoDB using C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, serialization, mongodb-.net-driver

I have an XML file and I want to convert to BsonArray in MongoDB, later then I can make it a list of elements. Here is what I tried.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("Books.xml");
string json_doc = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
...
using (var jsonReader = new JsonReader(json_doc))
{
    var context = BsonDeserializationContext.CreateRoot(jsonReader);
    var document = XML_collection.DocumentSerializer.Deserialize(context);
}
```

Code converts XML to Json but not BsonArray. That means what I will get is only ONE document with hundreds of fields. But what I want is making them separate as a list.

Comment: Could you show your simplified input and expected output ?

Comment: I just used a random XML for example, this is my XML file
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms762271(v%3Dvs.85)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `BsonDocument.Parse()` to read your string and then you can access `catalog.book` path to cast into `BsonArray`:

```
var json_doc = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
var bsonArray = BsonDocument.Parse(json_doc)["catalog"]["book"].AsBsonArray;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It helped. But I also have another question.
Let's say the XML has more than just 2 elements, how could I expand the code?
    `var bsonArray = BsonDocument.Parse(json_doc)["catalog"]["book"]["Ele_02"]["Ele_03"].AsBsonArray;`
Would that help?
In case the XML file has a lot of element, is there any way to do that?